# Java service cant write to text file

Tags: java, file, service

When I run the following code in eclipse it works as intended however when I install it and run as a service only the PNG file is output.

```
    int maxBound = 0;
    try 
    {
        File outputfile = new File("image.png");
        ImageIO.write(drawImage(), "png", outputfile);

        File boundsfile = new File("bounds.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(boundsfile);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); 
        bw.write(maxBound+" ");
        bw.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        log.info(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The log file is being written to (elsewhere in the same class) however there are no error messages present. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: try this: `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(boundsfile.getAbsoluteFile());`.. Few days ago I had a problem when one of the test started to fail because it could not find the file (which was there) and when I changed the constructor from File to absolute URL it started to work..

Comment: I had tried this initially with no luck. In the end I removed the BufferedWriter altogether and it worked. Not sure what the exact problem was. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swapped it out for this instead, works now.

```
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("bounds.txt");
        fw.write(maxBound+" ");
        fw.close();
```

Not sure what the problem was but this works.